# Map value in module with for-each to output

Tags: terraform, openstack

I have a module that creates multiple resources for a list of names. So for each name supplied in a variable called `instances`, a set of resources (vm, ports, volumes) is created.
In the output of that module I want to have a map, that maps the instance (each value in `instances`) to the IP of an associated port.

This is the definition of the port

```
resource "openstack_networking_port_v2" "this" {
  for_each = var.instances

  name               = "port-${each.key}"
  network_id         = var.network_id
  admin_state_up     = true
  security_group_ids = var.security_group_ids
  fixed_ip {
    subnet_id = var.subnet_id
  }
}
```

Until now, I had this in the output of the module

```
output "int-port" {
  value     = openstack_networking_port_v2.this
}
```

and this where I used it

```
int-ip : module.my-instance.int-port["${var.deployment}-my-01"].all_fixed_ips[0]
```

After upgrading terraform, I need to add `sensitive = true` to the output, as the openstack provider has marked something as sensitive, which will lead to the output not being printed. (I know I can get it with `terraform output -json`)
So I want to just return the IPs I need in the output instead of the whole object, but I can't figure out how.

I tried the following things:

```
output "int-ip" {
  value = openstack_networking_port_v2.this.*.all_fixed_ips[0]
}
```

and

```
output "int-ip" {
  value = openstack_networking_port_v2.this[*].all_fixed_ips[0]
}
```

which gives me

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../../modules/ext-instance-v2/outputs.tf line 24, in output "int-port":
│   24:   value = openstack_networking_port_v2.this.*.all_fixed_ips[0]
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "all_fixed_ips".
```

I also tried

```
output "int-ip" {
  value = {
    for instance in var.instances:
    instance => openstack_networking_port_v2.this["${instance}"].all_fixed_ips[0]
  }
}
```

and

```
output "int-ip" {
  value = {
    for instance in var.instances:
    instance => openstack_networking_port_v2.this[instance].all_fixed_ips[0]
  }
}
```

which leads to that error

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../../modules/ext-instance-v2/outputs.tf line 19, in output "int-ip":
│   19:     instance => openstack_networking_port_v2.this["${instance}"].all_fixed_ips[0]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ openstack_networking_port_v2.this is object with 9 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

It feels like I'm very close, but just out of reach.
I'm not only interested in the solution, but also in an explanation why the things I tried, did not work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `openstack_networking_port_v2.this` is **map** due to `for_each`, it should be:

```
output "int-ip" {
  value = values(openstack_networking_port_v2.this)[*].all_fixed_ips[0]
}
```

**Update**

Based on the comments. The correct way is for the last attempt is:

```
output "int-ip" {
  value = {
    for instance in keys(var.instances):
      instance => openstack_networking_port_v2.this[instance].all_fixed_ips[0]
  }
}
```

This is required, as `instances` is a map, but you need a list. In this case, you want to use the list of keys in the for-each.

Comment: How can I access the value for a specific instance with this?

Comment: @toydarian Not sure what you want to do. My answers addresses your incorrect use of this map `value = openstack_networking_port_v2.this.*.all_fixed_ips[0]`.

Comment: I actually want to get a map that maps the instance to the fixed ip that has been assigned to it.

Comment: @toydarian If the code you provided in the question is actually your code, then the last attempt with `for instance in var.instances:` is correct. But the error message indicates that you are probably using different code from what you are presenting on SO. The error does not match the code on SO.

Comment: It was almost correct. Now it clicked, I needed `keys(var.instances)`, then it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The `[*]` operator ([Splat operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html)) is designed for producing lists only. The documentation says the following about [splat expressions on maps](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html#splat-expressions-with-maps):

> The splat expression patterns shown above apply only to lists, sets, and tuples. To get a similar result with a map or object value you must use [`for` expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html).
>
> Resources that use the `for_each` argument will appear in expressions as a map of objects, so you can't use splat expressions with those resources. For more information, see [Referring to Resource Instances](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html#referring-to-instances).

The simplest version of this with `for` expressions would be the following:

```
output "int-ip" {
  value = {
    for k, port in openstack_networking_port_v2.this : k => port.all_fixed_ips[0]
  }
}
```

This means to construct a new mapping where each element of `openstack_networking_port_v2.this` (a map of objects) is translated into an element that has the same key but has *just* the first IP address as the value.

An important difference in my example above vs. the ones in your question is that the `for` clause has two symbols: `k, port`. This means to put the key of each element in `k` and the value of each element in `port`. If you write only a single symbol, like `for port`, then Terraform will bind that to the *value* of each element rather than the key, and there is no straightforward way to find the key corresponding to a particular value, only to find a value corresponding to a key.

It would also be possible in principle to use [the `keys` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/keys.html) to repeat over the keys in particular, and then use the key to look up the element:

```
output "int-ip" {
  value = {
    for k in keys(openstack_networking_port_v2.this) : k => openstack_networking_port_v2.this[k].all_fixed_ips[0]
  }
}
```

This is equivalent to the other `for` expression I showed above, but is more verbose due to needing to refer to `openstack_networking_port_v2.this` twice. Therefore I prefer the two-symbol `for`, particularly in cases like this where the expression being mapped has a large number of characters in it.